# How can I override default privacy setting using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I got default privacy setting set to Custom (Only you) in my facebook.
Then I have the following code to create a photo album:

```
$privacy = Array('value'=>'ALL_FRIENDS');
$privacy =  (object)$privacy;

$albumDetails = array(
'name' => 'My album name',
'privacy' => $privacy
);
$facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $albumDetails);
```

After executing the code, album is created but the privacy is keep to Custom (only you), not All friends/friends. What's wrong in my code. Is there any special code to override the default privacy?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to set privacy for newly created Album](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7125614/unable-to-set-privacy-for-newly-created-album)

Answer (score 3):

i can't promise it !
in the developer docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

says

> "Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or
>   specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted
>   Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page,
>   event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on
>   Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the
>   target's Wall. "

this mean, the developer can't make privacy control on their app did user can control it from wall, and if then application use privacy statmen is make lost control of privacy settings :p

sorry my bad english :p

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the default privacy that the user stated in their configuration, unless you are overriding it to a more restrictive option.

Meaning that if the user's default configuration is set to "All friends", and you specify "Only me", it will work. But not the other way around, like you are trying to do